# Looping Over Each Unique Value

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

New to python and any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Ok, here's the scenario:

I have a data set that includes customer name, order number, number of evaporators on that specific order number and number of condensers on that specific order number.  My objective is to calculate the percentage of orders that include an evaporator and condenser for each customer.

This is the code I came up with so far.  The problem is that I can only specify one customer at a time this way. How do I make this run for each unique customer name?

```
 DEvap = []
 DComp = []
 Evap_Comp = []

 for row in data[1:]:
    Customer_Name = row[0]
    Sales_order_number = row[1]
    Compressor = int(row[2])
    Evaporator = int(row[3])
    Value = int(row[4])

if Customer_Name == "AIRCOOLER CORPORATION" and Evaporator > 0:
    DEvap.append(Value)

    if Customer_Name == "AIRCOOLER CORPORATION" and Evaporator > 0 and Compressor >0:
        Evap_Comp.append(Value)


total_evaporators = sum(DEvap)
total_evap_comp = sum(Evap_Comp)
attachment = total_evap_comp/total_evaporators
```

Here is a snippet of the data set.  It includes a column labeled value which I used to append the empty list with.

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to only loop through unique customers. This can be accomplished with the use of a set to store the names of customers you already looped through and a continue statement to skip over the repeat customers.

Something like this

```
customers = set()
for row in data[1:]:
    name = row[0]
    orderNo = row[1]
    compressor = int(row[2])
    evaporator = int(row[3])
    value = int(row[4])
    if name in customers:
        continue
    customers.add(name)
    # Check no of Compressors and Evaporators here
    # If customers have placed multiple orders, only their first one will be checked here
```

Edit: In reply to your comment, the only way I could think of doing this without modifying the original data set is to create a new data set with the customers name and total orders.

Something like this

```
totalOrders= {}
for row in data[1:]:
    name = row[0]
    compressor = int(row[2])
    evaporator = int(row[3])
    if name in totalOrders:
        totalOrders[name][0] += compressor
        totalOrders[name][1] += evaporator
    else:
        totalOrders[name] = [compressor, evaporator]
```

This code creates a dictionary keyed by customer name with the value being a list [compressors ordered, evaporators ordered]

Multiple orders by the same customer will only update their existing entry in the dictionary. Then its a simple matter of looping through the dictionary and checking if both list values are > 0.

Edit 2:

Sure there is a way to do that:

```
totalOrders= {}
for row in data[1:]:
    name = row[0]
    orderNo = row[1]
    compressor = int(row[2])
    evaporator = int(row[3])
    if name not in totalOrders:
        totalOrders[name] = []
    totalOrders[name].append([orderNo, compressor, evaporator])
```

Here you have a dictionary keyed by customer name with values being a list of lists.
I would be careful with multi-layered data structures, however. If they get too complex, it can make your code nigh unreadable and make making minor changes to the code quite difficult. Something like this shouldn't be much of a problem, though.

Edit 3:

In your original question, you stated you wanted to find the percentage of customers who bought both a condenser and an evaporator.

This would actually easier to do with the dictionary in my first Edit.

```
totalOrders= {}
for row in data[1:]:
    name = row[0]
    compressor = int(row[2])
    evaporator = int(row[3])
    if name in totalOrders:
        totalOrders[name][0] += compressor
        totalOrders[name][1] += evaporator
    else:
        totalOrders[name] = [compressor, evaporator]
evapCond = 0
for customer in totalOrders:
    if totalOrders[customer][0] > 0 and totalOrdrs[customer][1] > 0:
        evapCond += 1
percentBoth = evapCond/len(totalOrders) * 100
```

Here percentBoth would be the percentage of customers who bought both a condenser and an evaporator

To do this with the dictionary in my second edit, you would need a nested for loop

```
totalOrders= {}
for row in data[1:]:
    name = row[0]
    orderNo = row[1]
    compressor = int(row[2])
    evaporator = int(row[3])
    if name not in totalOrders:
        totalOrders[name] = []
    totalOrders[name].append([orderNo, compressor, evaporator])
evapCond = 0
for customer in totalOrders:
    cond = False
    evap = False
    for order in totalOrders[customer]:
        if totalOrders[customer][order][2] > 0:
             cond = True
        if totalOrders[customer][order][3] > 0:
             evap = True
    if cond and evap:
         evapCond += 1
percentBoth = evapCond/len(totalOrders) * 100
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  How would I go about this if I want to calculate the percentage for all orders placed under each customer and not only the first one.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks.  Is there a way to update the dictionary value for each key to be each order number placed by the customer with the corresponding evaporator and compressor value? Basically can I update the values for each customer to be a list of lists where each list within the list is [ordernumber, compressor, evaporator]? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Perfect! You are awesome. Thank you!

Comment: One more questions.  Is it possible to now use some sort of if statement or calculation like the one in my original post on the list of lists values in the new dictionary?  Would I have to create a new dictionary with the results?

Comment: I got the following error when running the second code:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: I'm actually looking to find the percentage of orders that evaporators and condensers were bought on the same order for each customer, not necessarily the percentage of customers that bought both. I need a percentage for each and every customer.

Comment: For that, you just need to loop through each customer's list of orders and keep track of how many orders have both evaporators and condensers. Then compare to the length of that list.